# multiple projects on one vagrant box

Tags: vagrant, virtual-machine

I have two projects in these directories:`E:\projects\deep-learning` and `E:\projects\computer-vision`.
What I want to do is that both of them to be run on one box (like trusty.)
How to configure vagrantfile to both use the same box.

Comment: you want them to use the same box or the same VM (VM is created from the box and is the running instance) ?

Comment: I want them to be on one VM. But each project separate from other. In a way that from one project when I ssh I can't access other projects.

Comment: you could probably do that with some scripting but generally 1 VM = 1 Vagrantfile = 1 config so you want to share the 2 folders with the VM - now if you boot from 1 folder you dont see the other, you need to have some scripting to know if which directly you are running the command and disabled the sharing with the other folder.

Comment: Yeah your solution looks ok, But I'm used to create several projects. each projects takes 1GB, so I will soon become low on memory :)

Comment: clear .. but the thing is isolation, if you really want to isolate one project from another, best is to run on different VM, otherwise run a single VM and just share with the different folders being able to access the different projects

Comment: @Frédéric Henri I got it, tnx.